# string comparison on date format wont work?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, linq, web-services

Hi for some reason I cant do a string comparison on a date? Take for example:

```
public List<HireDate> GetHireDate(string anything)
{
List<HireDate> hiredate = hiredates.Where(n =>
string.Equals(n.HireFromDate, anything, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
).ToList();
return hiredate;
}
```

It simply wont work? if I type into a textbox `13/07/2012` which is how its stored it returns a 404 not found???

The output looks like this from a generic list/get request:

```
<ArrayOfHireDate>
<HireDate>
<HireFromDate>13/07/2012</HireFromDate>
<HireToDate>28/07/2012</HireToDate>
<NumberOfDaysHired>15</NumberOfDaysHired>
</HireDate>
</ArrayOfHireDate>
```

Is there another way to find a string with a forward slash in it? For instance using / in any of web string comparers does not work it will always throw a 404 not found?

Comment: Is n.HireFromDate is a Date object or a string object ? In the case of a date i would specify the date format using n.HireFromDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")... How it simply doesn't work, it doesn't compile ?

Comment: HireFromDate is a `public string HireFromDate` it compiles i get a 404 not found tho. I narrowed it down to the string comparison tho.

Comment: If it would be a normal asp.net server i would have say what the iis error is saying but i have never worked with wpf before ... a simple 404 seems strange to me .. no ?

Comment: 404 not found is a rest response saying it did not find what you sent.

Comment: For everyone reading this question: while I cannot answer the question, this question is about ASP.Net. More background information (the context, and the source of the 404s) can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11659847/146622).

Comment: Using this code :

    var a = new{HireFromDate="01/07/2012"};
    var b = new{HireFromDate="03/07/2012"};
    var c = new{HireFromDate="13/07/2012"};
    var hiredates = new[] { a,b,c }.ToList();
    var items=hiredates.Where(n=>string.Equals(n.HireFromDate, "13/07/2012", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
).ToList();
    items.Dump();

I've verified in linqpad and the list give the right items, so there's no reason that doesn't work ... try look at your datasource,  verify your anything variable and verify that your page doesn't have another error

Comment: @XhkUnlimit it seems to be a rest based issue, you cant have / in resources (uris)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1) To put a string in another string, the most common way to do this is using [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx). That method takes a format string (such as `"Date: {0} Time: {1}"`) and a bunch of arguments. Each occurrence of `{0}` in the string is replaced by the first argument, `{1}` by the second, etc.. There are additional options to format the arguments in the string, see for more information [the MSDN page on `String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx).

2) If you have an URL and you get a 404 in your application, first verify that the syntax of the URL is correct. Manually try the URL you create in your program directly in your browser, and if it does not work, find out what syntax is actually used to provide the arguments. For example, it might be that a date must be formatted as `13-07-2012` instead of `13/07/2012` for it to work. If so, you can probably solve this by choosing the appropriate [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya.aspx).

For any `DateTime date` object, to format it has a short date using any `CultureInfo` you want, use an overload of `ToString` and specify `d` as the format. For example, using the invariant culture:

```
var str = date.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Other format strings can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).