# DateTime.TryParseExact method for string comparison

Tags: c#, linq

Hey how can you do a string comparison match for a given date, `DateTime.TryParseExact` seems like the sensible option but I am not sure how to construct the arguement in the below method:

```
public List<Dates> DateEqualToThisDate(string dateentered)
{
    List<Dates> date = dates.Where(
        n => string.Equals(n.DateAdded, 
                           dateentered,
                           StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ToList();
        return hiredate;
 }
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660423/string-comparison-on-date-format-wont-work

Comment: Useful reference for people using the LINQ query syntax instead http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003697/how-to-i-use-tryparse-in-a-linq-query-of-xml-data

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know the format of the date/time exactly (i.e. it never changes, and does not depend on the culture or locale of the user), then you can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx).

For example:

```
DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
    str,                            // The string you want to parse
    "dd-MM-yyyy",                   // The format of the string you want to parse.
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,   // The culture that was used
                                    // to create the date/time notation
    DateTimeStyles.None,            // Extra flags that control what assumptions
                                    // the parser can make, and where whitespace
                                    // may occur that is ignored.
    out result))                    // Where the parsed result is stored.
{
    // Only when the method returns true did the parsing succeed.
    // Therefore it is in an if-statement and at this point
    // 'result' contains a valid DateTime.
}
```

The format string can be a fully specified [custom date/time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) (such as `dd-MM-yyyy`), or a [general format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) (such as `g`). For the latter, the culture matters as to how the date is formatted. For example, in the Netherlands dates are written as `26-07-2012` (`dd-MM-yyyy`) whereas in the US dates are written as `7/26/2012` (`M/d/yyyy`).

However, this all only works when your string `str` contains only the date you want to parse. If you have a bigger string with all sorts of unwanted characters around the date, then you'll have to find the date in there first. This can be done using a regular expression, which is a whole other topic in itself. Some general information about regular expressions (regex) in C# can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595.aspx). A regular expression reference is [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html). For example, a date similar to `d/M/yyyy` can be found using the regex `\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is to convert your date from `string` to `DateTime`.  If it is possible I would keep `DateAdded` as `DateTime`.

Bellow is a code that runs in LINQPad

```
public class Dates
{
    public string DateAdded { get; set; }
}

List<Dates> dates = new List<Dates> {new Dates {DateAdded = "7/24/2012"}, new Dates {DateAdded = "7/25/2012"}};

void Main()
{
    DateEqualToThisDate("7/25/2012").Dump();
}

public List<Dates> DateEqualToThisDate(string anything)
{
    var dateToCompare = DateTime.Parse(anything);

    List<Dates> hireDates = dates.Where(n => DateTime.Parse(n.DateAdded) == dateToCompare).ToList();

    return hireDates;
}
```